# Fail to bind socket using C ftp

Tags: c, ftp

I'm a networking student and I'm doing a project on socket programming in c using ftp. It's been a while now me and my partner couldn't figure out why our bind failed, We couldn't even get pass the binding. When we tried the same code on the client server for some reason it worked. I'm not even sure if the rest of the code below can run because we haven't got pass this. Sorry to trouble you guys but we're not actually the brightest student in our class.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>    //inet_addr
#include<string.h> // starlen
#include<unistd.h> // write
#define PORT 20

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    //declaration
    int socket_desc, new_socket , c;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client; 
    char *message;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //Please enter the ip address of your Server VM
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    
    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");
    
    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);
    
    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");
        
        //Reply to the client
        message = "Hello Client , I have received your connection. But I have to go now, bye\n";
        write(new_socket , message , strlen(message));
    }
    
    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    
 //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected \n");
return 0;
}
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    //declaration
    int socket_desc, new_socket , c;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client; 
    char *message;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //Please enter the ip address of your Server VM
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    
    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");
    
    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);
    
    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");
        
        //Reply to the client
        message = "Hello Client , I have received your connection. But I have to go now, bye\n";
        write(new_socket , message , strlen(message));
    }
    
    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code to support your question.

Comment: sorry was figuring out how to post my code just now but posted!

Comment: Why there is a connect call in the main? Is your main function posted twice?

Comment: ***my partner couldn't figure out why our bind failed***  Read [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html). Check the return value section. If bind fails, it returns -1 and errno is set. You can print the errno and its corresponding error message using strerror(errno).

Comment: [`perror`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) is fast to use.